# JDBC Oracle UDT (User Defined Type) VARCHAR value returns `?`

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbc

I use JDBC to execute stored procedure in Oracle. When I try to retrieve UDT values which are outputs of the stored procedure call, and then I try to access contents of UDT, I can access number but when I try to access VARCHAR value then it returns ???.

```
create or replace TYPE   type_springboot_test as object
(
 AGE NUMBER(10,0),
 NAME VARCHAR(500),

 CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION type_springboot_test RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)
```

MyJDBC UDT return value like `type_springboot_test(32,???)`

Comment: udt = User Defined Type.

Comment: Answer in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9469471/259889

Basically you need to add `orai18n.jar` to your classpath.

Comment: is it enough to add project dependecy?